# How to make image dynamic when there is class in image tag in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, themes

great community! 
How can I make Image dynamic where there is inline css class in image tag. If I remove all image tag with the post_thumbnail function the style is missing. I tried with the following code but below image it shows ( **" />** ). [single image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiv9A.png)
 Could you please tell me how to solve this issue? Thanks a lot

```html
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive img-blog" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function **the_post_thumbnail** already outputs a img tag. So your code has to look like:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php 
     the_post_thumbnail('large', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive', 'img-blog' ));
  ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the problem following your code but slightly in different. This way.. the_post_thumbnail('large', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive', 'img-blog' ));